# swift 5.3 - CGColor.init(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: 1.0) returns NSObject for macOs

Tags: swift, cgcolor

I am trying to create a CGColor in Swift 5.3 in macOS Catalina 10.15.7, using:

```
let colour : CGColor = CGColor.init(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: 10.0)
```

but the returned object is a NSObject. Same result as using

```
let colour : CGColor = NSColor.init(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: 10.0).cgColor
```

The NSColor is created correctly but at retrieve the CGColor, the result is NSObject.

Some suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: alpha = 1.0. Sorry.

Comment: Where is the part where you "retrieve the CGColor"?

Comment: What I'm asking is how you "know" the CGColor is not a CGColor. Of course it's a CGColor.

Comment: I create a NSColor using `let color = NSColor.init(red: 0.4434, green: 1.0, blue: 0.4343, alpha: 1.0)` the resulting object is a valid **NSColor** object, then I try to use in a graphics context to draw some lines in a view using: `let coreColour : CGColor = color.cgColor` the resulting object is a **NSObject** not a **CGColor** object, then the result is a invisible colour.

If I use `let coreColour : CGColor = NSColor.red.cgColor` the resulting object is a valid **CGColor** object, then the draw line is in red.

Comment: I see In Xcode Debug console.

Comment: eg:

`func color(_ red : CGFloat, _ green : CGFloat, _ blue : CGFloat) -> CGColor
{
    let r = red / 255.0
    let g = red / 255.0
    let b = red / 255.0
    
    let colour =  NSColor.init(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: 1.0)
    let coreColour = colour.cgColor
    
    return coreColour
}`

in debug console.

colour : NSColor: 0x000333434000002
coreColour : NSObject: 0x00000000009872

Comment: Yes but put that _in your question_. That is what the question is about, not some loose line.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are examining this object in the variable pane of the Xcode debugger. Sure enough, it is listed there just as an NSObject. But that's because it is what we call a *pseudo-object*. The CGColor type is not a true object type, even though Swift tries to disguise it as one; it is actually a CFType, which is an opaque struct — an Objective-C struct. You can discover this by opening the triangles:

[image]

To Objective-C, then, this isn't even an object. But for purposes of presentation and manipulation — i.e., to make it possible to pass it around as you are doing in your code — it has been wrapped up in an NSObject.

The outcome is that you can't tell anything about this thing in the variables list on the left of the debug pane. But in the *right* of the debug pane you can ask for a description which is useful. Thus, put a breakpoint at the `return` statement in your function, and when you pause there, say this in the console:

```
(lldb) po coreColour
```

You will see something like this:

```
<CGColor 0x6000026224c0> [<CGColorSpace 0x6000026085a0> (kCGColorSpaceICCBased; kCGColorSpaceModelRGB; sRGB IEC61966-2.1)] ( 0.784314 0.784314 0.784314 1 )
```

Comment: Yes, I use print(coreColour) and I reed `<CGColor 0x600002617de0> [<CGColorSpace 0x600002614600> (kCGColorSpaceICCBased; kCGColorSpaceModelRGB; sRGB IEC61966-2.1)] ( 0.176471 0.176471 0.176471 1 )`, but why the desired color is not draw?, only a black line.